# How to dump one database to another database using mysql?

Tags: mysql

i have tried the following query but i gate with an error.

```
mysql> mysqldump test |mysql test1;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqldump test |mysql test1' at line 1
mysql> mysqldump test |mysql test1
-> ;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqldump test |mysql test1' at line 1
mysql>
```

Comment: You have to do it outside of the mysql console

Comment: you have to use command prompt for that.

Comment: without console how can i do it

Comment: @adiintern not without console. You should do it in the command promp of your OS not inside of the mysql console

Comment: IIt is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use these commands on command prompt.

**Syntax :**

```
mysqldump --opt -u [uname] -p[pass] [dbname] > [backupfile.sql]
```

i.e.

```
C:\>mysqldump --all-databases > dump.sql
```

If you want to create dump for any specific database then you have to mention that database name in the command.

```
C:\>mysqldump --databases yourdb > dump.sql
```

To import the database you have to use following command,

```
C:\>mysql -p -u[user] [database] < dump.sql
```

Comment: will it copy along with tables created in old database or it wont@Pirate

Comment: yeah, because you have mentionned all-databases. If you want to create only particular db then you have to give that db name only.

Comment: Error occurs:
mysqldump: Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) when trying to connect

Comment: did you give credentials?
mysqldump -u [user] database > dump.sql

Comment: No i didnot give credentials

Comment: try mysqldump -u[username] -p[pass] [yourdb] > dump.sql